# How can I force override methods to call super in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have an abstract view controller that has some functions. Some view controllers will extend the abstract one and override some functions. I need to force some functions when any view controller override them, to call super.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you make your public methods `final` and expose empty `internal` methods that do nothing in the abstract class but get called in your public `final` methods.

Something like this:

```
class AbstractViewController {
    internal func willDoStuff() {
    }

    internal func didDoStuff() {
    }

    final public func doStuff() {
        willDoStuff()
        // Do the stuff 
        didDoStuff()
    }
}

class RealViewController : AbstractViewController {
    override internal func willDoStuff() {
        print("Will do stuff")
    }
}

let viewController = RealViewController()
viewController.doStuff()
```